# How can I add zoom effects to a Slick Slider and maintain smooth slide transitions?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, slick.js

I'm using Slick for my carousel and I want to have the images automatically zoom in and zoom out. Here's a [demo of my code](https://codepen.io/will_beaumont/pen/abMwmBz). This code is adapted from [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrswoop/pen/VLqPOm).

As you can see, when the first and third images finish their zoom in animation they revert to their initial state, *even though I'm using `forwards` in the `animation` property.* The second image, with the zoom out animation, jumps abruptly to being fully zoomed out for some reason.

One major difference between my code and the initial CodePen is that the latter has this selector:

```
.myKenburns .slick-slide[aria-hidden="true"] img {
    visibility: hidden; }
```

But this messes with the fade transition so that you no longer get a cross-fade. It just fades out and fades in, which I don't want. That's why I have it commented out.

Any ideas? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What browser and os are you using? I'm not seeing what you're describing, seems fine to me. The only odd thing is slide one zooms small to large, slide two zooms large to small, slide three zooms small to large, and then it goes back to slide one small to large. That looks like it jumps from small to large, small to large. If you added a fourth slide, it would look perfect to me. You might to create a gif to show your issue if this isn't what you're seeing.